# Rails devise gem and modal windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise, modal-dialog

Can you give me good tutorial for changing static devise login/registraion to ajax-based in modal window? Now i have it done like modal, but it is not ajax. Also in "google" there are tutorials, but all them are for login only. But i need to login using ajax, and! modal window. Are there good tutorials, advices etc? Could not find good one in internet.
with login is all ok, i see yours code... but **how to do in such way registration**? in web there is anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/jni-/Rails3-devise-ajax-login

Comment: You will not find a tailored tutorial.  This one has what you need implemented.  You just have to tweak the approach to your needs.

Comment: but register is another action, with it's method

Comment: i need registrarion in partial, what to write in what class?

Comment: hey, didn't know? with login is all ok, i see yours code... but how to do in such way registration? in web there is anything...